# Extracting initials with R

Tags: strings, r

Playing around in `R` with a Edx CS50 [homework](http://cdn.cs50.net/2016/x/psets/2/pset2/pset2.html#initializing). The job is meant to be done in `C`, I am using (the more familiar) R just for warmup.

I mainly wonder whether I am breaking any good practice/style norms overall or in any tiny detail.

```
initials <- function(full.name) {
  # Returns initials of a full name
  # Input will contain only letters (uppercase and/or lowercase) plus 
  # single spaces between words. Folks like Joseph Gordon-Levitt, 
  # Conan O’Brien, and David J. Malan won’t be using your program. (If only!)
  if (length(full.name) == 0) {
    stop ("Valid name please")
  } else {
    isspace  <- integer(0)
    fn.split <- unlist(strsplit(full.name, fixed = TRUE, split = ""))
    isspace  <- which(fn.split == " ")
    init     <- toupper(fn.split[c(1, (isspace+1))])
  return(paste(init, collapse = ""))
  }
}

initials("Stack Overflow")
[1] "SO"
```

Comment: If you'll consider regex, I think this will do: `toupper(gsub("\\W*\\b(\\w)\\w*?\\b\\W*", "\\1", full.name))`. And there must be nicer variations.

Comment: With `gsubfn` packge it's even shorter: `gsubfn("([A-Z])[a-z]*[ ]*", ~x, full.name)`.

Comment: The last part of the regex @flodel shows is redundant, you need only:
\\W*\\b(\w)\\w*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a bug. `length` doesn't return the length of a string, but the length of a vector. The function you need is `nchar`.
This problem reveals that you haven't tested your program enough.
Always look for corner cases and test well.

A minor thing, but when you reach a `stop` statement, the rest of the function will not be executed, so you could remove the `else` block,
making the code more "flat", which is typically more readable.

As far as good practices go,
in R, it's generally not recommended to use `return` statements,
especially when there is a single point of return from the function.
So I recommend to simply omit the `return` statement at the end of the function.

Putting the above tips together:

```
initials <- function(full.name) {
  # Returns initials of a full name
  # Input will contain only letters (uppercase and/or lowercase) plus 
  # single spaces between words. Folks like Joseph Gordon-Levitt, 
  # Conan O’Brien, and David J. Malan won’t be using your program. (If only!)
  if (nchar(full.name) == 0) {
    stop ("Valid name please")
  }
  isspace  <- integer(0)
  fn.split <- unlist(strsplit(full.name, fixed = TRUE, split = ""))
  isspace  <- which(fn.split == " ")
  init     <- toupper(fn.split[c(1, (isspace+1))])
  paste(init, collapse = "")
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Very useful. But it seems to me that your first statement (using return is bad) is at least contentious. See for example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11895446.

Comment: @snoram fair enough. I demoted that statement, by moving to the end, and with a bit more arguments against using `return`.

Comment: (funny, I wrote that thing you linked to... but no offense @janos, I don't always use return :-))

Comment: @flodel funny thing is, it turns out I upvoted that linked answer a long time ago and forgot about it

Answer (score 2):

On top of the topics discussed in janos' answer, the coding style of your code could also be improved:

---

Running [lintr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lintr/index.html) on your code produces two notes:

- line 5:  lines should not be more than 80 characters.
- line 12: Put spaces around all infix operators.

Although lintr sometimes produces questionable notes, both of the conventions mentioned above are supported by both [Hadley Wickham's R style guide](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/style.html) (also available in a [different version](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Style.html)) and [Google's R style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/Rguide.xml).

---

In line 7 there is a space before the left parenthesis. This doesn't belong there and should be deleted. Again, both of the mentioned R style guides agree on this.

---

The naming of your parameter, `full.name`, is a bit more controversial. Google's R style guide fully supports the naming style used in your code:

> Don't use underscores ( `_` ) or hyphens ( `-` ) in identifiers. Identifiers should be named according to the following conventions. The preferred form for variable names is all lower case letters and words separated with dots (`variable.name`), but `variableName` is also accepted; function names have initial capital letters and no dots (`FunctionName`); constants are named like functions but with an initial `k`.

Hadley Wickham's R style guide however explicitely discourages it:

> Variable and function names should be lowercase. Use an underscore (`_`) to separate words within a name. [...]
>
> Although standard R uses dots extensively in function names (`contrib.url()`), methods (`all.equal`), or class names (`data.frame`), it’s better to use underscores. For example, the basic S3 scheme to define a method for a class, using a generic function, would be to concatenate them with a dot, like this `generic.class`. This can lead to confusing methods like `as.data.frame.data.frame()` whereas something like `print.my_class()` is unambiguous.

Personally, I would recommend using underscores, exactly for the reason stated by Hadley Wickham and because I am not aware of any benefits of using dots over using underscores.

---

Incorporating this in the code posted by janos yields:

```
initials <- function(full_name) {
  # Returns initials of a full name
  # Input will contain only letters (uppercase and/or lowercase) plus
  # single spaces between words. Folks like Joseph Gordon-Levitt,
  # Conan O’Brien, and David J. Malan won’t be using your program.
  # (If only!)
  if (nchar(full_name) == 0) {
    stop("Valid name please")
  }
  isspace  <- integer(0)
  fn.split <- unlist(strsplit(full_name, fixed = TRUE, split = ""))
  isspace  <- which(fn.split == " ")
  init     <- toupper(fn.split[c(1, (isspace + 1))])
  paste(init, collapse = "")
}
```